# The best way to synchronize access to shared memory for a single writer and multiple reader scenario?

Tags: linux, posix, ipc

I have several process which may access a shared memory block. Only one process would write to the shared memory occasionally, several other process may read from the shared memory occasionally. 
I wan't to implement the following scenario:

1. the reader should wait until the writer is not writing before it read from the shared memory;
2. the writer should wait until no reader is reading before it write to the shared memory;
3. the readers could read from the shared memory simultaneously.

I tried using process shared mutex and flags in shared memory to implement this scenario (the process shared mutex is used to protect the flag):

1. when the writer want's to write to the shared memory:
   wait until reader flag is 0 --> set writer flag to 1 --> write to shared memory --> set writer flag to 0
2. when the reader want's to read from the shared memory:
   wait until writer flag is 0 --> increase reader flag --> read from shared memory --> decrease reader flag

The code is like:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t rw_mutex;
    int read_flag;
    int write_flag;
} shared_data_t;
void read_start(shared_data_t *p_data)
{   
    while (1)
    {   
        pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        if (p_data->write_flag <= 0)
        {   
            p_data->read_flag++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            usleep(1);
        }
    }
}

void read_finish(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
    p_data->read_flag--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
}

void write_start(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        if (p_data->read_flag <= 0)
        {
            printf("set write flag to 1\n");
            p_data->write_flag = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            usleep(1);
        }
    }
}

void write_finish(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
    p_data->write_flag = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
}
```

The writer's writing process is like:

```
write_start(p_data);
//write data
write_finish(p_data);
```

The reader's reading process is like:

```
read_start(p_data);
//read data
read_finish(p_data);
```

The code works but I haven't tested if there are any potential bugs.

I think there must be some better way to implement this scenario. 
Any suggestion is appreciated!

**EDIT1:**
I tried to use condition signal to replace the use of usleep and the code looks a litter better.

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t rw_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t rw_cond;
    int read_flag;
    int write_flag;
} shared_data_t;

void read_start(shared_data_t *p_data)
{   
    while (1)
    {   
        pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        if (p_data->write_flag <= 0)
        {
            p_data->read_flag++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&p_data->rw_cond, &p_data->rw_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        }
    }
}

void read_finish(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
    p_data->read_flag--;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&p_data->rw_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
}

void write_start(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        if (p_data->read_flag <= 0 && p_data->write_flag <= 0)
        {
            printf("set write flag to 1\n");
            p_data->write_flag = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&p_data->rw_cond, &p_data->rw_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
        }
    }
}

void write_finish(shared_data_t *p_data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
    p_data->write_flag = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&p_data->rw_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&p_data->rw_mutex);
}
```

Comment: suggestions, have a `readers_count` on number of readers. Before the writer `pthread_cond_broadcast` to the readers, set this to a `remaining_readers`. Each reader should atomicity decrement `remaining_readers` and the one that gets a 0 after this should `pthread_cond_signal` the writer. each reader can have its own mutex as they don't conflict. The writer mutex is also handled by cooperative reader signalling.

Comment: @danblack Signal the writer when the counter of remaining readers reached 0 is a good idea. Thanks!